# Android: get Embedded Resource image as drawable inside xml layout file

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, resources

Is there a way to set as `android:src` an embedded resource image with Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could not set the embedded resource from Forms project for it inside xml layout file via `android:src`.

`android:src` is used to set a drawable as the content. May be a reference to another resource, in the form `@[+][package:]type/name` or a theme attribute in the form `?[package:]type/name`. May be a color value, in the form of `#rgb`, `#argb`, `#rrggbb`, or `#aarrggbb`.

But you could get set the embedded resource in code behind.

A simple ImageView inside the layout. The code in Activity:

```
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout3);

        var imagview = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);


#if __ANDROID__
        var resourcePrefix = "App3.";
#endif
        // note that the prefix includes the trailing period '.' that is required
        var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MainPage)).Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream
            (resourcePrefix + "tiger_24.png");

        Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap;
        var bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
        imagview.SetImageBitmap(bitmap2);
```